# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.Native.dll breaks Intel fortran compiler installer

Tags: intel-fortran

Event log shows the following error.

```
Faulting module path: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup\x86\x86\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.Native.dll
```

Each time that I run the installer. And it does not allow me to repair or uninstall the compiler.

I added to the dll full permissions. Should I install a module for VS or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better solution, just rename the file to some other name, run installer, then restore the name of the file.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that the new C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup\x86\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.Native.dll, that probably comes with MSBuild (or VS installation), is not the one that installer expects (wrong API or something else).

With [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.Native.v3.0.4492.23473+b15bd3af75.dll](https://www.file.io/021f/download/chgpQqwrr5Uw) it will work! (PS: the link expires in one year)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).